# Separate viewmodel for page with Pivot into individual viewmodels

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, pivot, mvvm-light

I am using MVVMLight, i have created standard view and viewmodel. In view i have placed Pivot:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <local:FirstPivotItem />
        <local:SecondPivotItem />
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Here how my Pivot item looks like:

```
<controls:PivotItem x:Class="Pivot.WindowsPhoneControl1"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    // standard references and settings
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480" Header="First One">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    </Grid>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

In code-behind

```
public partial class WindowsPhoneControl1 : PivotItem
{
    public WindowsPhoneControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I want to create viewmodel for this pivot item, and then work with it as i do with standard views.
I will use

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PivotChangedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

to handle selection changing event and than inform appropriate viewmodels by Messanger.
I do not know how can i use possibilities of viewmodel in Pivot Item class, that is inherited from PivotItem but not from ViewModelBase, as i need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard PivotItem control for the individual items and put user controls inside each of them. Each user control can then have its viewmodel as the data context.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
            <local:PivotUserControl1 />
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <controls:PivotItem Header="second">
            <local:PivotUserControl2 />
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you know what the pivot items are going to be in advance or if they are dynamically created based on data. I'll assume its the first, judging by what you've written so far.

The way I've done this before is to have a number of PivotItem view models as public properties on the parent viewmodel, one for each pivot.
Then just set the dataContext of each PivotItem to the correct viewmodel property on the parent viewmodel.

this way you may be able to get away without the selection changed event. 
You can also subscribed directly to any events on the view models so don't necessarily need to bother with messaging for communication as all communication can go through the parent view model.

The second approach, if you're not sure in advance exactly what pivot items you'll have is to have a collection of PivotItemViewModels on the parent view model- one per pivot item, each inheriting from a common base class or interface. Bind that collection to the ItemSource of the viewmodel.

This is slightly trickier as you then have to determine what control to display but you can do this via a converter, if you have the Templates stored somehwere as a resource :

```
public class PivotItemToTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((int) value)
        {
            case 1:
                return Application.Current.Resources["Control1Template"];
            case 2:
                return Application.Current.Resources["Control2Template"];
            default:
                return Application.Current.Resources["Control3Template"];
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

you can then create a pivot item template for your pivot items and use the converter to get the correct control within it based on a value. in this case imagine the shared base viewmodel has a property ViewModelId which effctively identifies which control you'll be interested in:

```
<ContentControl 
                Content="{Binding}"
                ContentTemplate="{Binding ViewModelId,
                                          Converter={StaticResource PivotItemToTemplateConverter }}" />
```